# Вставить данные в mysql через php

Tags: php, mysql, запрос

Здравствуйте.
Есть список, выводящийся на странице, с текстовым полем для изменения

```
 while ($row = $todb->fetch_array())
  { echo $row[id];
    echo $row[name];
    echo '<input type="text" name="text['.$row[id].']"
    value="'.$row[pages].'"><br>';
  }
```

При нажатии на кнопку, данные, которые были введены в поле `text input` должны быть записаны в базу, т.е. если такой `id` и `pages` существует, то сделать `UPDATE`, а если не существует, то `INSERT INTO`.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
    {
    $text = !empty($_POST['text']) ? $_POST['text'] : null;
    foreach($text as $idt => $pages) {
       if ($pages != NULL)  {                   //idt это id товара
                                                //pages это значение
          $todb = $mysqli->query('UPDATE extendtovar 
                                  SET pages = "'.$pages.'"
                                  WHERE extendtovar.id = "'.$idt.'"');
            }
            else {
            $todb = $mysqli->query('INSERT INTO extendtovar (id, pages) 
                                   VALUES ("'.$idt.'", "'.$pages.'")'); 
            }
        } 
    }
```

При таком запросе UPDATE проходит нормально, а INSERT INTO вставляет значения 0 в поля, которые были не заполнены.
При запросе

```
elseif ($pages != "") {
        $todb = $mysqli->query('INSERT INTO extendtovar (id, pages) 
                                VALUES ("'.$idt.'", "'.$pages.'")');    
            }
```

не вставляется ничего.
Как в итоге сделать такую логику:

- Если число существует, то UPDATE этой строки
- Если число не существует, и его ввели в поле, сделать INSERT INTO
- Если число не существует, и его не вводили в поле, ничего с ним не делать

Comment: Вместо сравнения с NULL используйте empty().

Comment: мне кажется, что даже с empty(), при вводе числа в текстовое поле, скрипт идет по пути UPDATE, то есть если поле не пустое (а я ввел там число), то выполнить UPDATE, а в базе то этой строчки еще нет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрите внимательно код. У вас условие, если введенные данные не пустые, обновляем запись, если пустые, вставить запись. Что просите, то и получаете.
Используйте insert into on duplicate update

```php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $text = !empty($_POST['text']) ? $_POST['text'] : null;
    foreach ($text as $idt => $pages) {
        if ($pages != NULL) {     
            $todb = $mysqli->query('INSERT INTO extendtovar (id, pages) 
                                   VALUES ("' . $idt . '", "' . $pages . '") 
                                   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE pages = "' . $pages . '"');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Странно, я понимаю эту строку, но добавляю число в поле и ничего не записывается в базу. делаю var_dump, и вижу что переменная передается, да даже echo выводит эти данные

Comment: разобрался, добавил в запрос ON DUPLICATE и все заработало. Спасибо!